# Things to do before deploying an AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs

What are all the steps to do before deploying an Angular app? I'm thinking:

- Lint
- Minification

Anything else that I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget the unit testing and End2End testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set up your Angular-project with [yeoman](http://yeoman.io) and [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) you should have all the steps together:

- hints
- tests
- cdn-ify
- minify
- uglify
- minify css
- minify html
- revisioning